# How to remove "Click here to enter text" for empty contents in docx4j

Tags: java, xml, docx4j

I am using docx4j 3.1.0 to convert data from xml into word. If there's no content (null) in one field, then it will generate "Click here to enter text" in the exported file. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: check whether it is null if so write ""

Comment: Thanks, I would have a try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a file OpenDoPE/placeholder.xml to your classpath, containing for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rStyle w:val="PlaceholderText"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t> </w:t>
</w:r>
```

Comment: Could you please tell how you Actually did this? Where do we add the file? @Manuela

Comment: place that file to your classpath and docx4j will pick it up automatically. (for spring boot is `resources` folder) @user2493028